# Observable's events not received

Tags: scala, observable, rx-scala

I have a variable called `responses` of type `Observable[Try[Int]]` that emits either:

`Success(n)`, where `n` is a natural number
or
`Failure(Exception)`

I am summing the values of this observable like this:

```
val sum = responses.foldLeft(0) { (acc, tn) =>
  println("t1 tn: " + tn)
  println("t1 acc: " + acc)
  tn match {
    case Success(n) => acc + n
    case Failure(t) => acc // Failures are 0
  }
}
```

The print statements show this:

```
t1 tn: Success(1)
t1 acc: 0
t1 tn: Success(1)
t1 acc: 1
t1 tn: Success(1)
t1 acc: 2
t1 tn: Success(2)
t1 acc: 3
t1 tn: Failure(java.lang.Exception)
t1 acc: 5
t1 tn: Success(3)
t1 acc: 5
t1 tn: Success(3)
t1 acc: 8
t1 tn: Success(3)
t1 acc: 11
```

Immediately after, I am trying to get the sum from the observable like this:

```
var total = -1
val sub = sum.subscribe {
  s => {
    println("t1 s: " + s)
    total = s
  }
}
```

However, here, `total` is never updated and the print statement never shows anything.

Why is this the case?

Why are events not passed along any more?

Comment: Your sum seems to be an Int type after the fold operation. How are you running a subscribe on an int value?

Comment: It's `Observable[Int]`, not `Int`

Comment: The result of a fold operation is of the same type as the starting value of the acc which is 0 in your case. So the fold operation should return an Int. I might be missing something here???

Comment: Your code works fine for me, prints t1 s: xx

Comment: Is it asynchronous? If so, then it may be because the main thread exits.